# How to find the outline of a country given the imperfect outlines of its administrative subdivisions?

Tags: computational-geometry, regions

I have a larger outline divided into several regions.  While my data represents something else, let us think of this as the provinces/counties of a country, for the sake of simplicity.  This is, for example, a 90 degrees rotated Uzbekistan I made for illustration purposes:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

What I have is the polygon for each subdivision, as above.  What I want to get is the outline of the whole country, as below:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**How can I get the big outline starting with the outlines of the individual subdivisions?**

The problem is that in my data the subdivision outlines do not fit perfectly because they have been simplified slightly to reduce the number of data points. Thus if I try `BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[Graphics[polygons]]`, I get the error

> BoundaryMeshRegion::binsect: The boundary curves self-intersect or cross each other in ...

It is important that the result should be in the same coordinate system as the input data.  The result should be in vector format (polygon or region).  A small loss of precision is acceptable.

---

Below you'll find the code to artificially generate sample data that has this difficulty.

```
poly = #["Polygon"] & /@ CountryData["Uzbekistan"]["AdministrativeDivisions"] /. GeoPosition -> Identity;

spoly = poly /. Polygon[{line_}] :> Polygon@SimplifyLine[line, 0.01];

Graphics[spoly]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Update:** An alternative problem dataset, without the need to run simplification: `spoly = #["Polygon"] & /@ CountryData["Chad"]["AdministrativeDivisions"] /. GeoPosition -> Identity;`

`SimplifyLine` is a simple implementation of [the Ramer-Douglas-Peucker algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm) that I use here to artificially create the difficulty I have in my actual data (which unfortunately I cannot post).  Code is below:

```
rot[{x_, y_}] := {y, -x}

Options[SimplifyLine] = {Method -> "RamerDouglasPeucker"}

SimplifyLine::method = "Unknown method: ``.";

SimplifyLine[points_, threshold_, opt : OptionsPattern[]] :=
    With[{method = OptionValue[Method]},
      Switch[method,
        "RamerDouglasPeucker", rdp[DeleteDuplicates[points, #1 == #2 &], threshold],
        _, Message[SimplifyLine::method, method]; $Failed
      ]
    ]

rdp[{p1_, p2_}, _] := {p1, p2}
rdp[points_, th_] :=
    Module[{p1 = First[points], p2 = Last[points], b, dist, maxPos},
      b = Normalize@rot[p2 - p1];
      dist = Abs[b.(# - p1) & /@ points];
      maxPos = First@Ordering[dist, -1];
      If[
        dist[[maxPos]] < th
        ,
        {p1, p2},
        rdp[points[[;; maxPos]], th] ~Join~ Rest@rdp[points[[maxPos ;;]], th]
      ]
    ]
```

Comment: Sorry to comment outside the context of the question, can you let me know what is the meaning of `SimplifyLine::method = "Unknown method: ``.";` and its usage in `Message[SimplifyLine::method, method]; ` or direct me to any source that can help me understand this. thank you

Comment: @Algohi It just issues a message.  The last part of this [tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Messages.html) deals with how to set up your own messages.

Comment: I'm guessing you've already seen Mark's implementation of Douglas-Peucker [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3695)?

Answer (score 13):

The issue with `BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[Graphics[polygons]]` can sometimes be resolved by discretizing each polygon individually and taking the RegionUnion.

```
RegionUnion[BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics /@ spoly]
```

However for the Chad polygons there is a problem - `BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics` doesn't like some of them and returns unevaluated. I don't understand the reason for this, but it appears that rounding the coordinates helps. You can then use [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/102546/862) to find the outer boundary.

```
spoly = #["Polygon"] & /@ 
    CountryData["Chad"]["AdministrativeDivisions"] /. 
   GeoPosition -> Identity;

spoly = spoly /. x_Real :> Round[x, 0.0001];

br = RegionUnion[BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics /@ spoly];

merged = MeshRegion[MeshCoordinates[br], 
   br["IndexedBoundaryPolygons"][[br["BoundaryGroups"][[All, 1]]]]];

GraphicsRow[{Graphics[{Yellow, EdgeForm[Red], spoly}, Frame -> True], 
  RegionPlot[merged, AspectRatio -> Automatic]}]
```

[image]

The hack with `Round` is rather unsatisfactory, of course. Hopefully someone can explain what causes BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics  to fail on some polygons and provide a better fix.

Comment: The failure of `BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics` to cooperate with the 3rd and 15th polygon is rather mysterious indeed. For #3 I thought it might be the south-most region where [the border is drawn very strangely (and probably incorrectly)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/pTlpT.png), but removing this part makes no difference. Removing numbers 3 and 15 from the list (`RegionUnion[BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics /@ 
  spoly[[Complement[Range@Length@spoly, {3, 15}]]]]`, where `spoly` is the one above without `Round`) makes the kernel crash. [cont'd]

Comment: ...  I noticed that each of the polygons has a list of lists of coordinates as argument (i.e., {{{x1,y1},{x2,y2},...{xn,yn}}}) which is an acceptable syntax that can be used to pass various (possibly disjunct) polygons to a single `Polygon` function. Removing the outer pair of curly brackets yields polygons that can still be drawn and on which `BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics` does work. However, `RegionUnion` doesn't seem to like working on those: `RegionUnion[BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[Polygon[#[[1, 1]]]] & /@ spoly]` yields [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/AV70o.png). Looks buggy to me.

Comment: Interesting this: you really should study the output of `InputForm[
   BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics@Polygon[{{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 0}, {#, 0}}}]] & /@ {10^-5, 10^-11, 10^-12}`.

Comment: Also very interesting and revealing: `BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics@
   Polygon[{{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, 1} + {#, 0}, {2, 0}}}] & /@  {10^-5, 10^-11, 10^-13}`

Answer (score 13):

[image]

As I already pointed out in chat and similar to @Kuba's solution, a reasonably simple approach is to render the set of outlines as polygons. Due to the image grid, small differences at the borders are closed. And even if not, there exist many image filters to close gaps.

Once you have rendered the outlines, you are stuck with image pixel coordinates and you lost your original coordinate system, but with storing the original plot-range, this coordinate transformation can be reversed.

One of the important steps when you have your outlines as binary image is to get an ordered list of boundary pixel coordinates. To my knowledge, no built-in *Mathematica* routine exist that does exactly (and only) this. There are imperfect solutions like [`FindCurvePath`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindCurvePath.html) or things like [`FindShortestTour`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindShortestTour.html), but these lack of an important thing: They don't know about image pixels, their neighborhood and that we have a solid object. What they do is trying to find a path based on a set of points, which is a harder problem.

Therefore, let me give an implementation of an algorithm that can be found in [[Gonzalez & Woods](http://www.imageprocessingplace.com/DIP-3E/dip3e_main_page.htm)] in chapter 11.1 which works directly on the image pixels and traces the boundary around the object.

This algorithm works by starting at the uppermost, leftmost object-pixel b0. This object-pixel's left neighbor is obviously a background pixel c0. From this neighbor, we go clockwise through all other neighbors n1, n2, ... of b0 until we find another object-pixel b1. The neighbor before b1 was of course a background-pixel that we set to c1.

This is basically, the iteration step. We start with a pair (b,c) and calculate the next pair by the above description. In *Mathematica* I can describe the iteration through all 8 neighbors by a repeated rotation:

```
NestList[
 Round[{{1/Sqrt[2], 1/Sqrt[2]}, {-(1/Sqrt[2]), 1/Sqrt[2]}}.#] &, 
  {-1, 0}, 8]
(* {{-1, 0}, {-1, 1}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, 
   {1, 0}, {1, -1}, {0, -1}, {-1, -1}, {-1, 0}} *)
```

Therefore, a function that takes `{{bx,by}, {cx,cy}}` where `b` is the object pixel and `c` its background-neighbor, and a set of all object-positions `pts` could look like this

```
With[{rot = {{1/Sqrt[2], 1/Sqrt[2]}, {-(1/Sqrt[2]), 1/Sqrt[2]}}},
 nextPairC = Compile[{{p, _Integer, 2}, {pts, _Integer, 2}},
   Module[{n0 = Plus @@ ({1, -1}*Reverse[p]), n1 = {0, 0}, 
     b = First[p]},
    Do[
     n1 = Round[rot.n0];
     If[MemberQ[pts, b + n1],
      Break[];
      ];
     n0 = n1, {8}
     ];
    {n1 + b, n0 + b}
    ]
   ]
 ]
```

Since this is the core of the algorithm, the rest is a short wrapper around this. In the following, we use `NestWhileList` to repeatedly apply `nextPairC` until we reach the starting point. Exactly, the stop-condition reads: do until we reach an object point that is equal to b0 **and** its next object neighbor is equal to b1:

```
MooreBoundaryTracking[img_Image] := Module[{
   pixel = PixelValuePositions[img, 1], 
   p0, p1
  },
  p0 = {#, # - {1, 0}} &[First[SortBy[pixel, {Last, First}]]];
  p1 = nextPairC[p0, pixel];
  NestWhileList[
    nextPairC[#, pixel] &, 
    p1, 
    #1[[1]] != First[p0] && #2[[1]] != First[p1] &,
    2,
    10^5][[All, 1]]
 ]
```

The method runs about 2 seconds for image-sizes of about 1000 pixel. With `spoly` as defined in Szabolcs question:

```
img = Rasterize[Graphics[spoly]] // ColorNegate // Binarize;
Graphics[Line@MooreBoundaryTracking[img]]
```

Comment: Guys, please give me a million upvotes if you like, but **don't forget to upvote Simon and Kuba**, because my answer only answers a small sub-problem, while theirs give a solution for the whole question!

Answer (score 12):

Not sure what an outline really is so maybe:

```
Composition[

   Graphics[GraphicsComplex[#, Line@Last@FindShortestTour@#], Frame -> True] &

  , Function[image,
       Transpose @ MapThread[
            Rescale[#, {#2, #3}, {##4}] &, 
            {Transpose[#], {0., 0.}, ImageDimensions@image, 
             Sequence @@ Transpose@{{5, 25}, {13, 25}}}
        ] & @ PixelValuePositions[image, 1]
    ]

  ,  Binarize
  , Thinning
  , EdgeDetect
  , Binarize
  , ColorNegate
  , Rasterize[#, ImageSize -> 500] &

  ] @ Graphics[
  spoly,
  PlotRange -> {{5, 25}, {13, 25}},
  ImageMargins -> 0]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  This is halfway there.  What's missing is the ordering of the boundary points.  In other words, I would like a `Polygon` as the output.  Based on another post (see chat), `FindShortestTour` will often work for getting the right ordering.  (`FindCurvePath` will not).  Handling shapes with holes in them (i.e. not singly connected) is more trouble, but I didn't mention that intentionally: I might be able to work around that.

Comment: Can you add the `FindShortestTour` and make it into a `Polygon`?

Comment: @Szabolcs Yep, I skipped it thinking maybe there is a faster method for such "obvious" and dense set.

Comment: For this data, FindShortestTour returns the result instantaneously and the result is good.  Going to test for more complex cases soon.  I think that for such cases fast heuristics will usually return the best solution (shortest tour).

Comment: @Szabolcs Ok, done. Good luck.